# The site abruptly stopped adjusting to PC resolution

Tags: css

i've just been programming my site and when i redacted jsx code it abruptly stopped adjusting to PC resolution. Also, I redacted width and it mostly helped, but I need more width and it worked well earlier. Finally, I couldn't find problem. Can u guys help me fix it?

by the way, i use JSX and maybe it can help

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
    return (
            <div id='screen'>
                <div id='main'>
                    <header>
                        <ul>
                            <h3 id='title'>AroProg</h3>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" className='ours'>О нас</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" className='ours'>Продукты</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"className='ours'>Цены</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <button className='logs'>Создать</button>
                    </header>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #f4f7ff;
    
}

#main {
    margin-top: 60px;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 1200px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}

#title{
    color: rgb(2, 187, 2);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

.ours{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: color .4s ease;
}

.ours:hover{
    color: rgb(2, 187, 2);
}

ul li{
    list-style: none;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.logs{
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(2, 187, 2);
    padding: 15px 26px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: background-color .4s ease;
}

.logs:hover{
    background-color: rgb(0, 146, 0);;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I've updated your code to a runnable code snippet.  Can you indicate specifically what isn't working as expected?  If you're referring to the styling for any particular element, can you be specific about what style rules aren't having the expected effect?

Comment: when screen is lower than 1920x1080p I don't see left part of screen and overflow-x appears.

Comment: My browser is currently narrower than 1920px (somewhere around 1600px) and everything appears to render fine for me.  When it gets lower than around 1200px I do see a horizontal scroll.  But this is expected because the `#main` element has an explicit width of `1200px`, so it's always `1200px` wide.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes. But it worked correctly.. well, I must make @media to fix it.